# vue2, view-router screen transition issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can't speak English, but vue is worse. I apologize.
I am working on page conversion after login using view router.

I am develop the screen below.
[Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9cgY.png)

The current screen is not exposed normally.
I think you are misunderstanding router-view.
I will show you my code. What could be wrong?

The calling sequence is as follows: index.html -> App.vue -> Login.vue (real first page) -> Main.vue

Route.js

```
import Menus from "../components/LeftSideMenu.vue";
import Login  from "../views/Login.vue";
import Main from "../views/Main.vue";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const route = [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path : "/main",
        name : "main",
        components: {
            default: Main,
            MENU: Menus
        },
    }
]
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Login.vue

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In" @click="login">
      </div>
    </template>
<script>
methods: {
 login() { this.$router.push("/main")
}
</script>
```

Main.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MENU/>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: what is not working ? please add details

Comment: My intention is to show two screens, a side menu and a view, but the side menu is not displayed at all.
Only the main screen appears, but I guess it's because there is only one router-view displayed in the app.I have no experience so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what you are lagging here use the following correct in your code. Hope it will work for you.

### Routes.js

```html
import Menus from "../components/LeftSideMenu.vue";
import Login  from "../views/Login.vue";
import Main from "../views/Main.vue";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const route = [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path : "main",
        name : "main",
        component: Main
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you. I proceeded with single page routing referring to the code, and it was launched as a component on the page and proceeded as intended.